# Need the proper object declaration for my XStream deserialization

Tags: java, xml, object, xstream

My XML:

```
<autocomplete>
  <url_template>http://api-public.netflix.com/catalog/titles/autocomplete?{-join|&amp;|term}</url_template>
  <autocomplete_item>
    <title short="Star Wars: Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back: Original Theatrical Version"></title>
  </autocomplete_item>
</autocomplete>
```

My Objects:

```
public class AutoCompleteList
{
public String url_template;
public List<AutocompleteItem> autocomplete_item;
}

public class AutocompleteItem
{
public Title title;
}

public class Title
{
@XStreamAlias("short")
public String Short;
}
```

My code:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("autocomplete", AutoCompleteList.class);
xstream.alias("title", Title.class);
AutoCompleteList myObj = (AutoCompleteList)xstream.fromXML(stringFromStream);
```

I am unable to retrieve the "title short" value from the XML.

Also, if my XML has more than one set of autocomplete_item tags, xstream errors out complaining that there is a duplicate instance of autocomplete_item.

Any suggestions?

I have searched through the many questions here but nothing seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `short` attribute, try adding an `@XStreamAsAttribute` annotation:

```
public class Title
{
  @XStreamAlias("short")
  @XStreamAsAttribute
  public String Short;
}
```

and call `xstream.processAnnotations(Title.class)` before you call `fromXML`.

For the multiple `autocomplete_item` issue you should use `@XStreamImplicit`

```
public class AutoCompleteList
{
  public String url_template;

  @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="autocomplete_item")
  public List<AutocompleteItem> autocomplete_item;
}
```

Again you'll need to call `xstream.processAnnotations(AutoCompleteList.class)` to tell XStream to read the annotations before you can call `fromXML`.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  Thank you.  That was driving me nuts.